# ld: library not found for -lssl when install psycopg2 in PyCharm terminal

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

when I using this command to install `psycopg2` in PyCharm terminal:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

shows error:

```
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=140001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/xid_type.o
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/aix_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/typecast.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg/xid_type.o -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-310-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

I could run this command in the macOS Monterey terminal, but did not work in PyCharm, what should I do to make it work in PyCharm terminal? I already tried to restart the PyCharm. Am I missing something? what is the different with the PyCharm terminal and macOS terminal?

Answer (score 4):

I tried to export `LIBRARY_PATH` in PyCharm terminal like this:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.1/lib
```

works.

Answer (score 3):

I tried install `psycopg2-binary==2.9.3` but it won't worked.

@Dolphin answer helped me but I needed change version from `3.0.1` to `3.0.5`

My commands in terminal

```bash
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.5/lib
```

```bash
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
```